# Python: Getting a sum of counts obtained in Python

Tags: python, count, sum

I am a beginner struggling with Python every day. I have a large data set that has Name of animals in the 2nd column. I have a program to add up the count of each animal by its name (each row has 1 animal Name and 1 "count" data). I am trying to get the sum of those count data I obtained using Python but I am not being able to do that. The code I have so far is:

```
import csv, collections

reader=csv.reader(open('C:\Users\Owl\Data.txt','rb'), delimiter='\t')

counts=collections.Counter()

for line in reader:
   Name=line[1]
   counts[Name]+=1

for (Name, count) in sorted(counts.iteritems()):
   Output=list('%s' % count) #Make output string to a list
   Sum=sum(Output) # Sum function requires a list
   print 'Total kinds of Animals: %s' % Sum
```

I get an error saying `"  File "sum_count.py", line 17, in <module> Sum=sum(Output) # Sum function requires a list TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'".`

What I have figured out so far is that because `sum` apparently require the input type to be a list, I converted the count data (which was string) to a list but when I do `Output=list('%s' % count)`, it seems that all the count data that are more than 2 digits are split. For example, when I print Output, it will be like this:

```
['1', '6', '3']
['3']
['1', '8', '5', '9']
['7', '9']
```

instead of

```
['163']
['3']
['1859']
['79']
```

What I want to do here is to get a single "sum" of these elements. Here, it will be 4. Four kinds of animals.

I am thinking that this may be the reason why I am getting the error above. I might be wrong but could somebody please help me how to solve this issue? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Why do you want an object of the form `['163']` instead of just `163`? `sum()` _does_ require the input type to be a list, but I think you're going about the list construction wrong. Also, strings are iterables and when you do `list(some_string)`, it turns that string into a list of characters.

Comment: You are right. I just want an object of the form just 163. In this case, I want Python to do 163+3+1859+79. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 4. I edited the question again. I am sorry to confuse you...

Comment: @JoelCornett `sum() does require the input type to be a list` - not true - it requires its argument to be anything that is iterable.

Comment: @JonClements: My mistake. That was what I meant, but you're absolutely right, I can't use those terms interchangeably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `sum`.

Try this:

```
for (Name, count) in sorted(counts.iteritems()):
    print 'Species total: %s' % count
```

Or, possibly better:

```
for (Name, count) in sorted(counts.iteritems()):
    print 'Total for species %s: %s' % (Name, count)
```

`sum` is for when you have a list of numbers and want to find the sum of that list of numbers.
You have already collected the sum number of each animal using `counts` -- you just need to display it.

**Edit**

To sum up the total number of animals counted, you can do this:

```
total = sum(counts.values())
print 'Total number of animals: %d' % total
```

**Edit 2**

The number of kinds of animals counted is simply the length of the `counts` dictionary:

```
print 'Number of kinds of animals: %d' % len(counts)
```

Comment: Will this add up each count for each Name? Before this code, I had something like this because I just wanted to know the count but now I want to add them up.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to get the total with `total = sum(counts.values())`

Comment: Or, to get the number of kinds of animals, `total = len(counts)` -- see edits to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for both edits! They are very clear!! Edit 2 is exactly what I wanted but knowing the difference really helps. Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 2):

(Re-written following comment discussion; original answer just pointed out that OP was trying to add strings.)

The other answers have more opportunities for extension (and so I would recommend them), but if you *only* want to quickly count the number of types of animals, you could simply count the number of lines in the file and use your knowledge of how the file is structured. For example, if your csv file has a header like `Name, Count, etc.` followed on the next lines by only the data you're interested in, the number of animals would be the number of non-empty lines in the file, minus one for the header. You could then print the count using the following code:

```
print sum(1 for line in open('test.csv') if line.strip() != '') - 1
```

Here's what each part of that code does:

- `sum()` add all of the elements of the list inside it. In this case, there is not a list inside, but a generator expression, which here can be thought of a list that doesn't get in memory.
- `1 for line in open('test.csv')` this is the first part of the generator expression. By itself, it would produce a generator whose length was the number of lines in `test.csv` and in which every element was `1` (the analogous list would be `[1,1,1,1,1]` if there five lines in the file).
- `if line.strip() != ''` this is the second part of the generator expression. It makes sure that a `1` is only added to the generator if the line has anything on it.
- `-1` one is subtracted from the value `sum(...)` returns to ignore the header of the csv

Well, I hope that helps in some way, and I should reiterate that this method is just a quick and dirty approach; you wouldn't use it if, for example, you were doing other stuff with the data.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! When I try "Output=int('%s' % count), I get an error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable". Should I do both int and list?

Comment: this is not a good answer. *Where*, exactly, would he do that cast? In his current architecture, he couldn't. He's a beginner to python. You're basically telling him "restructure your code, and make sure you cast to int somewhere". In addition, you've totally missed the real problem, which is that he's trying to sum a list of string, which, even if they WERE ints, should not be summed.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt True- I answered too quickly. I responded as soon as I saw that owl was summing a list of strings and intended to edit the answer to tailor it to his/her code. While I doing the edit, other people answered with the same info, so I cancelled it. Also, I misread the bit about what owl wanted summed. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @MatthewAdams I would try and edit it to do it the right way :) see if you can present a new take on how to do it right. As a beginner, I'm sure he'd like to see how lots of other people would do it.

Comment: Yes, learning different ways to do same thing indeed help me a lot! I am actually trying all of your codes (that is why my reply is not catching up). I really appreciate all of your help!! This is really a great community! :) Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: @MatthewAdams by the way, reversed my downvote to an upvote following your edit :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Getting counts

I think the problem stems from the fact that you are differentiating the "count" from the "total". The "count" *is* the total number of occurrences of that one item. Additionally, you are misusing `collections.Counter()`, which has the capability of making your job a *lot* easier. Here is a coded example of what I think you are trying to achieve:

```
counts = collections.Counter(line[1] for line in reader if len(line) > 1)
#Now all the occurrences of each item are summed up, AND ordered by number of occurrences

print "Total number of animals: %d" % len(counts)
#This is what I THINK you are trying to do.
```

Additionally:

```
for name, number in counts.items():
    print "# of %s: %d" % (name, number)
```

#### About your `TypeError`:

You have a list of strings, not a list of integers.

An example:

```
mylist = ['1', '2', '3']
```

All `sum()` does is perform cumulative addition on the iterable, similar to this:

```
total = 0
for item in mylist:
    total = total + item
```

In this case `total` is an `int` (value 0) and `item` is a `str` (value '1'). Python doesn't know what to do with `0 + 'string'`.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this but apparently, it still splits the numbers with multiple digits as the example above. Do you have any suggestion to avoid that?

Comment: @owl: See my comment on your question above. What is "species total". The reason I ask, is because it appears to me that you've already collected the totals into a your counter dictionary, and it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to print the total of all the items in your dictionary a bunch of times.

Comment: I just edited my question again. But here I want Python to do a two-step process. First count up each kind of animal, and then sum how many kind of animals there are. In the original data, it will be like [cat, cat, dog, cat, rabbit] but what I want is a sum of how many animals I have. So in this example here, I want a single sum, 3 (kinds of animals).

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted! Thank you so much and once again, my sincere apologies for getting confused with my own question!

Answer (score 0):

First you are using a Counter object, but only use it as a substitute for a defaultdict.
If you wantet to use it to do your counting you could have passed you input like this (assuming species appear more than once and you want to know how often each species appears):

```
counts = collections.Counter(map(lambda item: item[0], reader))
```

But if you want to count the sum of all animals (regardless of species) you have to add that count in  your first loop. And as other have said, since you are reading in strings you first have to make an integer out of that count.

```
import csv

reader=csv.reader(open('in','rb'), delimiter='\t')

counts = dict()

for data in reader:
    animal = data[1]
    if animal not in counts:
        counts[animal]= 1
    else:
        counts[animal]+= 1

for animal in counts:
    print 'Animals of scpecies %s: %s' % (animal, counts[animal])   

print 'Species total: %s' % len(counts)
print 'All animals: %s' % sum(counts.values())
```

Comment: Sorry I got late getting back but thank you too for your help! Currently I get an error saying "print 'All animals: %s' % sum(map(lamda item: item[1], counts.items())) SyntaxError: invalid syntax" When I remove this line, I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack". I have seen this error before but so far have not figured out what that means...

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting a syntax error... what version of python are you using? The ValueError indicates that at some point there are not enough values to unpack. Are there always two values in your file?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7. There is a ^ mark below item:. Any clue? Regarding ValueError, when you say two values, in my original data file? The file is actually very large and it has over 10 columns. That was why in my original code above, I had to specify which column I wanted to count, although this may not be relevant to the error I got here...

Comment: I changed so the unpacking will now work. In addition I removed the count that I thought was in addition to the name in the line and changed the last line to something equivalent. But basically now it is only a variation of Sam's answer.